# Ag-grid: clear cell when "agSelectCellEditor" is used

Tags: javascript, angular, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

As stated in the ag-grid [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/cell-editing/):

> The default editor will clear the contents of the cell if Backspace or
> Delete are pressed.

But this doesn't work when the "agSelectCellEditor" is used. If you press Delete or Backspace the cell will enter in EDIT mode and you can choose only the values that are provided as options.

Any idea how can I achieve the same behavior?

Comment: If you are using the community version, can you show the example via stackblitz?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Could not able to clear value using delete / backspace.
But I could see in ag grid doc plunkr page , If I pressed Delete key then the values are cleared. https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/provided-cell-editors/#select-cell-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article that explain how to write the delete cells logic. This works also for multiple cells. Please check this article: https://blog.ag-grid.com/deleting-selected-rows-and-cell-ranges-via-key-press/

Basically you override the default behavior of the DELETE or BACKSPACE keys using **suppressKeyboardEvent** callback in our default column definition:

```
defaultColDef: {
    suppressKeyboardEvent: params => {
        if (!params.editing) {
            let isBackspaceKey = params.event.keyCode === 8;
            let isDeleteKey = params.event.keyCode === 46;
            
            if (isBackspaceKey || isDeleteKey) {
              params.api.getCellRanges().forEach(range => {
              let colIds = range.columns.map(col => col.colId);

              let startRowIndex = Math.min(
                  range.startRow.rowIndex,
                  range.endRow.rowIndex
              );
              let endRowIndex = Math.max(
                  range.startRow.rowIndex,
                  range.endRow.rowIndex
              );

              clearCells(startRowIndex, endRowIndex, colIds, params.api);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the delete method:

```
function clearCells(start, end, columns, gridApi) {
  let itemsToUpdate = [];

  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    let data = gridApi.rowModel.rowsToDisplay[i].data;
    columns.forEach(column => {
      data[column] = "";
    });
    itemsToUpdate.push(data);
  }

  gridApi.applyTransaction({ update: itemsToUpdate });
}
```

This works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in 28.2.0, now delete key always clears the cell without entering the "editing mode".

Reference: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/releases/tag/v28.2.0, AG‑4801